# Using regular expression with gedit

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gedit

I am working on building a .lang file for TSO REXX scripts.   Rexx does not care about case so IF = if = If = iF ... I would like to have .lang file that is case insensitive with keywords but I can not figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out .. th e(?i) switch needs to be turned on.  also for GEDIT I will need to add an new context id that will have my statement I am trying to match

```
            <context id="leave_stmt" style-ref="keyword">
               <match>(?i)leave</match>
            </context>
```